# Mysql updating many fields

Tags: mysql

I want to update many fields randomly in a MySQL table, and I need to update two fields, one using unix timestamp and the other a date. For example, this is what I would have for the unix timestamp:

```
UPDATE `video` SET addtime= 1264982424 + (1355555555-1264982400)*RAND()
```

That should update the addtime randomly. However, there is another field in the table that is adddate and this uses mysql date. What can I do so that I write an addtime in Unix that is consistent with the adddate? I'm a bit of a noob in MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED:**
If you need to keep adddate field synchronized with addtime field, you could insert a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upddate BEFORE UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE video SET NEW.adddate=FROM_UNIXTIME(NEW.addtime);
END;
```

Comment: But that doesn't make the addtime the same as adddate I think, and if it does please explain me why :) Looks like addtime could be any random number and adddate could be a completely different date than that time.

Comment: @luquita: do you mean that you want `addtime` to represent the time held in `adddate`? So you set `addtime` to a random value, and then create a date representation of that time? If so, maybe [from-unixtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) is what you need.  It seems like an odd thing to do though.

Comment: @luqita: I really didn't understand your question. If you need what @Mike told in the above comment, do what he tells there. On the contrary explain what you need.

Comment: @luqita: if my answer is wrong because your quesion is different I gonna delete it.

Comment: @luqita, @Mark: take a look at my edited post. Is it what you need?

Comment: I was about to give a big fat -1 for the first part of answer. +1 for the trigger.

Comment: @Denis: the question is not really clear... look at Mike comment... he's asking what OP needs. Anyway I gonna delete first part, 'cause I've understood that it was not what OP needed... Thanks for giving me +1 and not -1 :)

Comment: Sorry maybe I did not explain myself well :( I used both solutions together and made two queries one like the one I had in my question and the second one using FROM_UNIXTIME... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about this one?

```
UPDATE video
SET addtime = 1264982424 + (1355555555-1264982400)*RAND(),
    adddate = FROM_UNIXTIME(addtime)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `adddate` will be syncronized with new time (after RAND and +)? I think it will be set to the old addtime... Correct me if I'm wrong, please!

Comment: Thanks... I used FROM_UNIXTIME(addtime) but after running the first query. Once I got all the addtimes randomized, I executed the adddate = FROM_UNIXTIME(addtime) to make the dates consistent with the addtime.

Comment: Yep that is good too if you don't have to update them from time to time, just once.

Comment: @luqita,@vbence: dont' you think (luqita) that the trigger is a better solution? In this way anytime you update addtime, you have adddate syncronized...

Comment: @vbence: it's a surprise to me that your query works!! Good to know, I always learn something new visiting this website :D

Comment: @Marco Trigger is certainly safer, but if the OP cared about a good quality database did not introduce the second field at all. (It contradicts normalization and makes no sense as a cache either.)